# Are data encrypted or just hashed in the Corda Ledger?

Tags: encryption, corda

Are the transactions and states stored encrypted or just hashed in the H2 database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corda doesn't control whether transactions and states are encrypted. This functionality is delegated to the node's database:

- If the node's database supports encryption of data at rest, this can be used to store the transactions and states in an encrypted form
- If the node's database supports encrypted JDBC connections, these can be used to transmit the transactions and states to the database in an encrypted form

For example, Azure SQL DBs are encrypted at rest.

Once SGX is integrated with Corda, transactions will always be encrypted using the enclave's private key, with only the SGX enclave able to decrypt them.